# Accessing a dictionary inside a dictionary

Tags: c#

I am trying to access a dictionary nested inside another dictionary.

The code I wrote is:

```
foreach (var entry in source)
{
    int i = 0;
    str = str + i + ": key: " + entry.Key + "; value = " + entry.Value +"; ";
    // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
}
```

and for some elements the value is System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]

I would like to access this dictionary when the inner value has a given value, as "Department".

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: What is the data type for source?

Comment: Is the `Key` a dictionary or the `Value`?  Using a dictionary as a key seems strange.

Comment: if you have a nested collection, you need 2 loops

Comment: @DStanley you are right. I had bad formatting on my output. It is actually the value

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to access this dictionary when the inner key has a given
>   value, as "Department"

Assuming you have  a dictionary like this:

```
var source = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<String, Object>>();

foreach (var outerEntry in source)
{
    foreach (var innerEntry in outerEntry.Value)
    {
        if(innerEntry.Key == "Department")
        {
            // do something
            Console.WriteLine("Key:{0} Value:{1}", innerEntry.Key, innerEntry.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.

Comment: @user1648371: you can see what kind of dictionary i'm using, what are you using?

Comment: It is shown as a string, but when I print the key it says Dictionary<String, Object>

Comment: Where is it shown as key and how do you print it? You have the source-code in front of you, so you don't need it's textual representation to identify the type. You cannot use a `Dictionary` as `Dictionary`-key. I mean, you can, but it's not a good idea since they are only be found if the reference is the same, not if they are _equal_.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Value` is a dictionary you could loop through the underlying dictionary keys:

```
foreach (var entry in source)
{
    int i = 0;
    str = str + i + ": key: " + entry.Key + "; value = "
    if (entry.Value is IDictionary)
    }
        str = str + " { "; 
        foreach (var innerentry in (entry.Key as IDictionary))
        {
           str = str + innerentry.Key + "; value = " + innerentry.Value +"; ";
        }  
        str = str + " } "; 
    }
    else
      str = str + entry.Value +"; ";
    // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
}
```